# Remove single quotes from array object

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
watch = ['52055690','52056600','52056603','52055260','52055255','52055276']
```

Here every object is coming with single quotes. I just need to get 
    array in following form

```
[52055690, 52056600,52056603,52055260,52055255,52055276]
```

I tried following

```
var range = [];
for (var i = 0; i < watch.length; i ++ ) {
  range.push( watch[i])
}
```

But still i was not able to make it out.
   Could anyone please help me out with it?

Comment: range.push(parseInt(watch[i]))

Comment: What @Brian said. Conceptually, you aren't trying to "remove single quotes", you're trying to *cast* or *parse* strings to integers.

Comment: `range.push(+watch[i])`

Comment: @MrKen that's a neat trick

Comment: @Brian , yes , i usually using it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use map() with Number() and it will return a new Array with numbers.

```js
var watch = ['52055690','52056600','52056603','52055260','52055255','52055276']
var result = watch.map(Number)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply convert the value to int.

`range.push(parseInt(watch[i]));`

Answer (score 2):

So I think you are trying to convert strings to integers. You can do this with the `parseInt` function. You can implement this to iterate over your array and convert each string like this:

```
var range = [];
for (var i = 0; i < watch.length; i ++ ) {
    range.push( parseInt(watch[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just parse the value to int or to float using the `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` functions.

You could try something like this:

```
var range = [];
for (var i = 0; i < watch.length; i ++ ) {
  range.push( parseInt(watch[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parseInt to convert string to number.

```
watch = ['52055690','52056600','52056603','52055260','52055255','52055276' ]
var range = [];
for (var i = 0; i < watch.length; i ++ ) {
range.push( parseInt(watch[i]))
}
console.log(range)
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()`, `Number()` constructor

```
var range = watch.map(Number)
```

Comment: That would create a number object, which is not usually what people want.

Comment: @JamesKraus _"That would create a number object"_ Not sure what you mean? `Number()` can accept a string and return a number representation of input string, which is what OP is expecting.

Comment: Nevermind, I confused it's behavior with the object constructor. TIL

Comment: This should be the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use parseInt to convert to number. Number could be used as well. Below is the code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < watch.length; i ++) { 
  range.push(parseInt(watch[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cast to integer.

```
var result = watch.map(parseInt);
```

```js
var watch = ['52055690','52056600','52056603','52055260','52055255','52055276'];
var result = watch.map(function(e) { return parseInt(e); });
console.log(result);
```